# How do I install lodash v3 Typescript typings

Tags: typescript, lodash, npm-install, typescript-typings, definitelytyped

Unfortunately I cannot upgrade to lodash 4 right now. So, I'm trying to use the v3 typings provided in  https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/lodash , which has a v3 folder with lodash 3 typings. However, when I do `npm install @types/lodash --save-dev` the v3 folder is not there. All I see is the `common` and 'fp' folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/lodash@3.10.2
```

You can see what other 3.* versions are available on the npm page:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/lodash

Comment: OMG thank you kind sir! You are definitely a genius! Someday I hope to be as smart, cool, and probably handsome as you